# CryptKeeper icon doesn't show up in the tray?

Tags: encryption

I'm trying to encrypt a folder, but the CryptKeeper icon doesn't show up in the tray.  I'm not sure why.  I've tried changing the whitlist to "all", but that didn't work.  How do I get CryptKeeper to show up in the tray?  Or, what would be an alternative to CryptKeeper?

Comment: The problem was fixed in recent (actually old) releases https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptkeeper/+bug/571473

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a bug.

Here is the bug report:

[Bug #760800 “Cryptkeeper icon do not appear on the gnome panel” : Bugs : “cryptkeeper” package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptkeeper/+bug/571473)

And a work around:

[How To Re-Enable The Notification Area (Systray) In Ubuntu, For All Applications ~ Web Upd8: Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-re-enable-notification-area.html)

Basically you run the following command :

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
```

See the link for a more detailed explanation and an graphical solution.

Comment: I did that, still no luck.

Comment: @IsaiahBugarin that has worked for me
any time you edit these types of settings you will have to restart your machine or simply logout and login again

Answer (score 2):

ok, Let us Solve this........
As a first step, let us check what are the white listed apps. for that open the terminal
(cntrl+alt+T) then type:

> gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist

This will display the whitelisted apps.
suppose it be

> ['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'scp-dbus-service', 'Update-notifier', 'desura']
>   that is crypt keeper is not listed.........
>   So all you have to do is list the crypt keeper and update unity.....
>   for listing the crypt keeper

type the following comand

> gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'scp-dbus-service', 'Update-notifier', 'desura', 'cryptkeeper']"

well it is listed and set...

Now reconfigure unity
for that type

> setsid unity

now some changes will happen in the screen and you will have your unity interface back in few seconds....... when you look at the systray you can find the Cryptkeeper icon.

(if crypt keeper was already present on your white list all you have to do is reconfiguring unity by typing above command)
All the best.

(truecrypt is another encryption software)

I also request you to add the Tag Cryptkeeper and Crypt Keeper to your question

------------------Edited------------------

If you want to start the crypt keeper when you start your OS. add crypt keeper to startup applications.

Comment: Didn't work....

Comment: are you getting cryptkeeper icon in unity dash?

Comment: Nope.  I can dock the icon there, but when I click on it normally, it doesn't appear in the dash.

Comment: Remove cryptkeeper... Then use autoremove function........ check then check the whitelists. if cryptkeeper is there remove it also.. then reinstall cryptkeeper. include cryptkeeper inthe whitelist as i mentioned above. THEN reconfigure unity using SETSID unity commnad (very important).. (If youare getting any error message please post it).. after some time (when it completes) open cryptkeeper from the unity.. your icon will appear in systray. from there you can operate. But when you restart it will dissappear. so you have to open cryptkeeper again from unity... Please let me know the result.

Comment: I get a bunch of "[insert file name here] does not exist" where "insert file name here" is a file.

Comment: check weather u reinstalled cryptkeeper after removing it? and when youare getting[insert file name here] does not exist" error? isunity is reconfigured after setsid?

Comment: I get the error after I try to launch Cryptkeeper.

Comment: you reinstalled cryptkeeper? normally after reinstalling and adding to whitelists t hasto com. reconfiguring unity with SETSID make s sure it comes..Ok if you renstalled, from where you are trying to launch?

Answer (score 2):

This was tricky, I use 12.04 and gnome-classic.  I had to use "add to panel" and then select "Notification Area".  I did also use the

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'cryptkeeper']"
```

In order for the icon to appear!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one - worked for me in 12.04!
[look at the "work around" I added to bug this morning]

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptkeeper/+bug/963522

SuperEngineer (suprengr) wrote 7 hours ago:

Workaround:
follow instructions at:
http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/04/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html
[copied below]
If you want to add support for Systray or Notification Area which has been disabled in Unity, install and launch dconf-editor from Ubuntu Software Center. Now to enable it just add an extra string 'all' under Desktop > Unity > Panel as shown in screenshot below (requires a logout to work). To revert, just click on 'Set to Default'.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist ['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'Update-notifier']

$ gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'Update-notifier', 'cryptkeeper']"
```

Comment: Please consider expanding your answer to include an explanation of some sort of what this command do.